# how to stop open/show code when click widget in Widget tree on vscode dart devTools

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test, devtools

when i use dart devTools inside the Visual Studio Code,
each time i click a widget in widget tree it's open/show the widget code line in a other tab 
do you guys know how to stop this?

Comment: what are you trying to do with devTools?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh actually I'm new in this, so just try figure out how it work

Comment: IMO it is ok to focus because we are using `Wdiget Inspector` as dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm just figure out by my self 
in vs‌Code: settings > Extensions > Dart > dart Dev‌Tools 
on (Dev Tools Location) select the active from the menu‌Bar
[image]